# Why does Gradle Android plugin generate non-camel-case multidimensional flavor build directories

Tags: android, adt, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

I have a multidimensional flavor project:

flavorDimensions 'dimenA', 'dimenB'

`android {
        productFlavors {
            foo {
                dimension 'dimenA'
            }
            dev {
                dimension 'dimenB'
            }
        }
    }`

So my combined flavor is "fooDev"

However, if I wanted to reference the full AndroidManifest.xml in my build directory, I will find it here:

```
build/intermediates/manifests/full/foodev/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

and not

```
build/intermediates/manifests/full/fooDev/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

And why does this matter? Some projects (i.e. Robolectric) look for required build files based on the `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` static var.

For example:

    `public final class BuildConfig {
      public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
      public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.foo.test";
      public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
      public static final String FLAVOR = "fooDev";
      public static final int VERSION_CODE = 9500;
      public static final String VERSION_NAME = "9.5.0";
      public static final String FLAVOR_dimenA = "foo";
      public static final String FLAVOR_dimenB = "dev";
    }`

Should Android Gradle use non-camel-case multidimensional flavor names for build directories (i.e. `build/../fooDev` instead of `build/../foodev`) or should projects like Robolectric use something else to reference build files and not just with `BuildConfig.FLAVOR`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'd argue that it's mostly a matter of the Google team needing to document the rules (e.g., "flavor directories are the concatenation of flavor names for all dimensions, in descending dimension priority, and converted to lowercase"). I'd further argue, therefore, that this is a better thing to either [file as an issue](http://b.android.com) or possibly ask [on the `adt-dev` Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/adt-dev), as I am skeptical that you will get an authoritative answer here.